# How to get the data type of a csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following data in a csv file:--

```
User_ID Date    Num_1   Comp_ID
101 4/14/2015   1   21
102 5/12/2014   11  1
```

Each column has a type.

I want to extract and manipulate the columns which has int data type.

Not sure why the following code is not working.

```
import csvkit
file_name ='file.csv'
with open(file_name,'r') as f:
    reader=csvkit.reader(f)
    header = reader.next()
    for items in header:
        if type(items) == int:
            print row
```

I am not getting any output when I run this.

Comment: `type(items)` will *always* be `str`, it won't be `int` unless you convert it to such.

Comment: How do i figure out the type of the column ?

Comment: `if items.isdigit()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can only read it as a `string` and then typecast that to `int`

converting `string` to `int`

```
def str2int(str):
    try : 
        return int(str)
    except : # handle this exception correctly
        print "error in str2int()"

print str2int("100")
print type(str2int("100"))
```

Comment: If you wanted to do something like this you should be more specific `except ValueError:`

Comment: @CoryKramer - yes thats right ! I just put a comment there for him to handle it however he wants.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `csvkit` but it seems that you didn't iterate over your rows, and `items` is just the rows. also you can not check the type with `type(items) == int` because `items` would be tuple. instead you need to loop over your items and check with `str.isdigit`

```
for items in header:
   for it in items :
      if it.isdigit():
        print it
```

Or you can use `filter` for example :

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(),['101','4/14/2015','1','21'])
['101', '1', '21']
```

or you can also use a list comprehension :

```
[it if it.isdigit() for items in header for it in items]
```